# Store tuples in an dictionary - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

Let's say I have a namedtuple:

```
tempTuple = namedtuple('tempTuple', 'lyrics num1 num2 num3')
```

and I want to store the namedtuple into a dictionary.

I create several objects such as:

```
temp1 = tempTuple("hello, goodbye", 1, 2, 3)

temp2 = tempTuple("final goodbye", 4, 5, 6)
```

How would store the tuples into a dictionary and be able to access it later?
If I want to print something such as the lyrics "final goodbye" how would I do that?

Comment: I don't see what the issue is. `namedtuples` are hashable and can be dictionary keys, as doing `{temp1: 1}` in the Python console clearly shows. Not sure what "How would store the tuples into a dictionary and be able to access it later?" means given that.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the namedtuples into the dictionary:

```
In [6]: test[temp1] = 'foo'
In [7]: test
Out[7]: {tempTuple(lyrics='hello, goodbye', num1=1, num2=2, num3=3): 'foo'}
```

edit: 
You can also use `test.keys()`.

Comment: I assumed OP wanted to store the tuples as values, not as keys.  I suppose he didn't make that clear.

Comment: And test[temp1].lyrics would throw an error because the string 'foo' has no property lyrics

Comment: @chapelo: Oops. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

namedtuples are stored in a dictionary the same way as any other object: (using the sample tuples you created above):

```
mydict = {}
mydict['tuple1'] = temp1
mydict['tuple2'] = temp2
```

Print the "lyrics" attribute like this: (using the namedtuple directly)

```
print(temp2.lyrics)
```

Or using the dictionary entry:

```
print(mydict['tuple2'].lyrics)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tuples are values in your dictionary, you privide a key and store the tuples.

```
your_dict['some_key'] = temp1
```

and you extract information either by position or name:

```
your_dict['some_key'].lyrics
your_dict['some_key'][0] # equivalent
```

If your tuples are the keys of your dictionary, something like a multiple key dictionary, they have to be unique, and you would do:

```
your_dict[temp1] = 'some_value'
```

In this case it does not make sense to access the fields of the tuple in relation with the dictionary.